# C# converting string data representation to typed

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Now Im writing a universal method for loading configuration data from XML. A lot of parameters in my case are stored in node attributes, so I decided to write a universal method for attribute reading:

```
    private static T ReadAttribute<T>(XElement Element,string AttributeName)
    {
        var attrib = Element.Attribute(AttributeName);

        if (attrib != null)
        {
            return attrib.Value; // off cource error is in this line !
        }
        else
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

This method should try to read attribute with specified name and if this attribute missed it should return default value for attribute type.  Attribute type is specified by T.
As it shown in comment above my problem is that I cant universally convert string value into specific type. Actually I plan use int, double and two enum types as T.
What way I should act in this situation? How I should convert string value into T type?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `Convert.ChangeType`. It does basically what you want. But it's a conversion not a cast, well, not just a cast.

```
return (T)Convert.ChangeType(attrib.Value, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The reason why you can simply cast a string to some arbitrary type is that the type system doesn't allow that. However `Convert.ChangeType` returns object which could be any type and therefore the cast is allowed.

The `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is important becuase XML content isn't shouldn't be encoded/decoded using different cultures. The XmlConvert class should be used if working with XML however it doesn't have a handy generic method like `XmlConvert.ChangeType`.

The `XAttribute` class has many explicit user-defined casts that map to the XmlConvert class. However, you cannot simply use these with a unconstrained type parameter T and expect the same result.

To make matters worse, XML and Convert doesn't actually play nice. So if you're really serious about this you would write something like this to handle the conversions.

```
static T ConvertTo<T>(XAttribute attr)
{
    object value;
    switch (Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)))
    {
        case TypeCode.Boolean: value = XmlConvert.ToBoolean(attr.Value); break;
        case TypeCode.Int32: value = XmlConvert.ToInt32(attr.Value); break;
        case TypeCode.DateTime: value = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(attr.Value); break;
        // Add support for additional TypeCode values here... 
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Unsupported destination type '{0}'.", typeof(T)));
    }
    return (T)value;
}
```

Comment: For those wondering, Convert.ChangeType requires the source object to implement IConvertible (unless the source already is the required type).

Comment: Is there a danger with this that the forward conversion has been done by XAttribute (with methods from XmlConvert), but that the reverse conversion will be done with Convert?  I don't know if there are corner-cases on, for example, DateTime, where the conversion might be different?

Comment: Yes! It works perfectly for now. Thank you! But how can I be sure that, for example, I cant use my method with hypothetical classA, for which dint exists conversion from string. As I understand its not right to simply specify `where T: IConvertible` it wouldnt yield sufficient results

Comment: @Will Dean - Yes there is. Using `Convert.ChangeType` will work in most cases however there are specific things being done by the `XmlConvert` class that isn't being done by the `Convert` class. It would be better to roll your own `ConvertTo<T>` which works properly with XML content.

Comment: @Anton Semenov You really can't, it's gonna throw a runtime exception if it's not possible. The up side of this is that it's a pretty neat syntax but it does have its pitfalls.

Comment: @John Leidegren: Ok I would be carefully use it) Thank you once again!

Answer (score 5):

I would go with the [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) stuff. It's basically a class that does conversions to/from values and cultures. The primary difference between a TypeConverter and [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx) is that the later requires the IConvertible interface on the source type, while TypeConverters can work with any objects.

I've created a helper class for this, since I often store different configuration objects in xml-files. That's also why it's hardcoded to convert to/from CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.

```
public static class TypeConversion {
    public static Object Convert(Object source, Type targetType) {
        var sourceType = source.GetType();
        if (targetType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceType))
            return source;

        var sourceConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(source);
        if (sourceConverter.CanConvertTo(targetType))
            return sourceConverter.ConvertTo(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, source, targetType);

        var targetConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetType);
        if (targetConverter.CanConvertFrom(sourceType))
            return targetConverter.ConvertFrom(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, source);

        throw new ArgumentException("Neither the source nor the target has a TypeConverter that supports the requested conversion.");
    }


    public static TTarget Convert<TTarget>(object source) {
        return (TTarget)Convert(source, typeof(TTarget));
    }
}
```

It's fully possible to create your own TypeConverter to handle system types, like System.Version (which doesnt implement IConvertible) to support conversions like from strings containing a version number ("a.b.c.d") to an actual Version object.

```
public class VersionTypeConverter : TypeConverter {
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType) {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            return true;

        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value) {
        var s = value as string;
        if (s != null)
            return new Version(s);

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType) {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            return true;

        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType) {
        var v = value as Version;
        if (v != null && destinationType == typeof(string)) {
            return v.ToString();
        }

        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

To actually use this provider you need to registered it during application startup, using [TypeDescriptor.AddProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x0wz2y6.aspx), passing in a custom [TypeDescriptionProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionprovider.aspx), and `typeof(Version)`. This needs to return a custom [CustomTypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.customtypedescriptor.aspx) in the [TypeDescriptorProvider.GetTypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xycabk1.aspx) method, and the descriptor needs to override GetConverter to return a new instance of VersionTypeConverter. Easy. ;)

Comment: Wow! It really powerful solution. Now Im trying to use it in my programm. Thank you!

Comment: I believe that all system types implementing IConvertible also has a TypeConverter already. The main reason why it's so much code needed is that the TypeDescriptor stuff wraps the whole reflection framework. Override CustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties to add/remove properties, and people using TypeDescriptor.GetProperties will see new stuff. You can make up your own properties and handle their storage on your own if you want.

Comment: @SimonSvensson very handy, and holy old posts batman, but is there a reason you try ConvertTo before trying ConvertFrom, and if so, could you add that to your *(now 3 year old)* answer? For my use case, I believe I am going to need ConvertFrom more often than ConvertTo, as I'm working with a custom ORM that maps ints, strings, etc. from the Database into known custom types;  an int converter.CanConvertTo() will always return false, and reads happen much more frequently than writes, so I am going to flip that order unless I'm missing something *(other than don't write/use a custom ORM)*

Comment: @Darmon, never really thought about it. There shouldn't be any issues unless you have rare cases with both the source converter's ConvertTo and the target converter's ConvertFrom claims that they can convert to the other type, and they differ in implementation. Somewhat contrived example, and I can't think of anything builtin that would do that.

Comment: @SimonSvensson Yes that seems like it would be not only rare but also probably an error in implementation; at least with any of the weird cases I can come up with! :-D I wasn't sure if you implemented in that order due to performance, or maybe a convention of calling `ConvertTo()` before `ConvertFrom()`. Thanks for the reply, I'm going to go with `ConvertFrom()` first because I'll be using that more often, so that will cut out several of the first ifs. That shouldn't make a huge difference but should be a bit less wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

Built-in methods won't help if T is a type defined by yourself. Let's say the xml looks like:

```
//some other segments
<Book Name="Good book" Price="20" Author="Jack" />
```

And you T is the class Book that looks like:

```
class Book
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public decimal Price { get; set; }
   public string Author { get; set; }
     //maybe some other properties
}
```

There is no magic to convert the `XElement` to an instance of `Book` automatically, you need to implement it yourself. An easy and general implementation is something like this:

```
    interface IXElementConvertible
    {
        void LoadFrom(XElement element);
    }

    class Book : IXElementConvertible
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }

        public void LoadFrom(XElement element)
        {
            this.Name = element.Attribute("Name").Value;
            //blabla
        }
    }
```

And you need to modify your method:

```
private static T ReadAttribute<T>(XElement Element,string AttributeName) 
                             where T : IXElementConvertible, new()
{
    T t = new T();
    t.LoadFrom(element);
       //just an example here, not the complete implementation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the following check in you code:

```
if (attrib.Value is T)
{
...
}
```

Comment: It work's like this @Dummy01. If you're wrong, you'll get a down vote because we don't want to promote wrong answers. However, if you're sincere and wan't to learn more I'd happly help you with that. Your suggestion actually disregards the rules of the type system entierly and it doesn't make any sense. The `Value` property is of type `System.String` it will never type test against `T` if `T` isn't a string. Which I don't see the point of doing, it doesn't solve the problem and it's clear to me, that you didn't understand the question.

Comment: You spent too many lines to make the teacher to me. I guess it fits perfect to the direct negative voting of yours. But for the story, yes you are right. I was wrongly remembering that Value is an object, and not a string, and that is where my check was coming from. In fact if you noticed what I just said I did wrong, is the easiest solution to your problem, and in that you will also use my check. But I don't risk another bad vote from the teacher so I guess you have to figure it out by yourself :)